# Где можно скачать нестандартный tabcontrol а именно чтобы на корешке была кнопка закрыть

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Где можно скачать нестандартный tabcontrol а именно чтобы на корешке была кнопка закрыть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать WPF. Писать для Windows Forms/vb свой велосипед. Использовать пакеты заменяющие стандартные контролы в winforms, [вот, например](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx), [вот, еще.](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/) Предоставляются полнофункциональной триалкой. После окончания триала - соответственно нужно покупать. Есть и бесплатные аналоги, но малофункциональны и нужно опять же гуглить. А можно заглянуть [сюда.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

Comment: Я уже весь инет облазил может есть какие нибудь примеры или учебник по WPF

Comment: я знакомился с wpf [тут](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level1/info_WPF.php), но само собой каждый сам избирает каким путем изучать...

Comment: @cas-live: WPF позволяет кастомизировать что угодно, вы сможете хоть в меню комбобокса засунуть по видеоплейеру. Переходите на него, не пожалеете. Сразу учите MVVM, без него получится говнокод.